# how to show a message in screen if the number is int or double in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, int, double, message

im doing a homework of learning java from a university and i dont know how to do this im trying to put a message if the user enter a number like "11" or wherever show a message like "this number is integer: 11" but if i write in screen 
22,4 show a message like "this number is decimal: 22,4"

we recently were seeing the use of "If , else, and boolean"

can u guys help me pls D:

regards

im working with this code

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class casa1 {
      public static void main (String[] args)
      {
         Scanner entrada;

         entrada = new Scanner(System.in); 

         float number=0;

         System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
         number=entrada.nextFloat();

         //heres when i dont know what to do for show a message if is int or double
         if(number==int){
         System.out.print("Your Number is decimal: ");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean checkInt(double someDouble)
{
    return someDouble == (int) someDouble;
}
```

Now with this you can check whether is int or not

Comment: what about 3 & 3.0 ?

Comment: thanks , but i have a question this public static goes down the public static void main or i have to replace? 

and how can i make it works in system.out.print?

Answer (score 0):

To check whether it is an int or double first, we could check whether it has decimal. For example:

```
if(number%1==0){//the type is int
    //TODO something delicious
}else{//the type is not int
    //TODO something interesting
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your definition of a "decimal" is the existence of a decimal point, and since you aren't validating the input as numeric, then:

```
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
String number = entrada.nextLine();

if (number.contains("."))
    System.out.print("Your number is decimal");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (entrada.hasNextDouble())
```

If this succeeds, it's a double, and you can get it via `double d = entrada.nextDouble()`.

```
else if (entrada.hasNextInt())
```

If this succeeds, it's an integer, and you can get it via `int i = entrada.nextInt()`.

You need to test for `double` first, of course.